# How to Redirect old ugly urls (still in Google cache) to the new working Beautified ones?

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, redirect, apache2

Given: first I **beautified my urls**, now all nice urls let server fetch the ugly pages below water. Most people do this and with some Stackoverflow it all worked out fine. Thanks to this magnificant online community.

Little problem: But, google still **has cached the old urls**, the ugly ones, and I would like to have then rediret for once and all via 301 visible permanent redirect to the nice ones.

Sothat all below instances

```
/xx/yyyyyyy?ln=xx
/yyyyyyy.php?ln=xx
/xx/yyyyyyy.php?ln=xx
```

Redirect forever (and thereafter) towards:

```
/xx/yyyyyy
```

And when no language given:

```
/yyyyyyy
/yyyyyyy.php
```

Redirect these both to:

```
/en/yyyyyyy
```

(Legend: `yyyyyyy.php` = webpagename like index.php  and    `/xx/` = 2 character countrycode  (optional)   and when NO xx is given, .

What golden rewrite rule makes this dream come true?
Your input is Much appreciated by me. I treat all suggestions as possible answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([^&]*&)*)(ln=[a-z]{2})&+(.*)
RewriteCond %3&%1%4 ^ln=([a-z]{2})&+(.*)
RewriteRule ^/([a-z]{2}/)?(.+)(\.php)?$ /%1/$1?%2 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond $0 !^/[a-z]{2}(/|$)
RewriteRule ^/(.+)(\.php)?$ /en/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But it might be a lot easier if you would do this with PHP as mod_rewrite is quite limited in its expressiveness.

Comment: thanks very much, but it doesnt work... any tips/links on how to enable logging on htaccess rewriting? Thanks very much +1